# msys2, using standard windows console

Tags: cmd, msys2

I use Console2 ([link1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) [link2](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx)), it's like a wrapper around the standard console, but allows to copypaste text with ctrl-shift-c and ctrl-shift-v. I find it much more comfortable than the consoles that come with msys2, they have like ctrl-ins shift-ins weirdness. And having two different consoles around isn't good.

How can I use Console2 to launch the compiler? I'd add C:\msys64\mingw32\bin to PATH, but I don't want to have too many exe and dll around in PATH, don't want to distribute something that depends on libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll by accident.

Also, I need to be able to switch between mingw32 and mingw64 compilers somehow.

Tried reading c:/msys64/msys2_shell.cmd, don't understand what's in it.

Switching to windows command line probably requires to move from unix shell commands to windows ones. I could rewrite some makefiles I'm working with, it's not that much of a problem.

Maybe I could go the other way, to use msys2 console in my everyday life. I only use it to launch youtube-dl and one other program I wrote anyway. It would require making copypasting easier, and some way to switch between mingw32 and mingw64.

Comment: Try this project https://github.com/userzimmermann/MSYS2-cmd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46015587/edit

Temporary solution: create three files `g3.bat`, `g6.bat` and `gg.bat`, and put them in one of the PATH directories. They allow to temporarily add or delete mingw32 or mingw64 in PATH.

`g3.bat`:

```
call gg.bat
SET PATH=%PATH%C:\msys64\mingw32\bin;
```

`g6.bat`:

```
call gg.bat
SET PATH=%PATH%C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;
```

`gg.bat`:

```
set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw32\bin;=%
set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;=%
```

Call this to check the result: `echo %PATH%`

---

Version 2, that tries to not use leading `;`

It almost works, but `gg.bat` still leaves leading `;` behind. I could use `set PATH=%PATH:;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin=%` instead (notice extra `;` to the right of `%PATH:`), but it would break if `C:\msys64\mingw32\bin` is at the beginning of PATH.

Also, I'm not sure if `""` is necessary there or not.

`g3.bat`:

```
call gg.bat
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin
```

`g6.bat`:

```
call gg.bat
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin
```

`gg.bat`:

```
set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw32\bin=%
set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw64\bin=%
set "PATH=%PATH:;;=;%"
```

---

Version 3, "eeh whatever":

`gg.bat`:

```
set PATH=%PATH:;C:\msys64\mingw32\bin=%
set PATH=%PATH:;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin=%

set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw32\bin;=%
set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;=%

set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw32\bin=%
set PATH=%PATH:C:\msys64\mingw64\bin=%

set PATH=%PATH:;;=;%
```

Comment: @eryksun Thank you, tried to fix it. Can you look at my new code, there are a few things that probably can be done better.