# Does cmake searches for gcc in %PATH%?

Tags: cmake

I want to be able to quickly switch between two compilers, 32bit and 64bit ones. I wonder if just adding correct bin directory to PATH is enough, or I must use CC and CXX?

Here is a [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014855/msys2-using-standard-windows-console), it's about how I add and remove compilers to PATH.

Comment: The answer is Yes. Did you encounter any problems with this approach?

Comment: @Florian sorta. It started building for VS2017, which keeps crashing anyway for me. Surprised it found it, it's not even in path. It's a different story though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

The short answer is, yes CMake will find the compiler in your `PATH` environment.

The long answer is

1. It looks what generator/build environment you have specified (e.g. Visual Studio generator searches also in Windows registry for installation paths)
2. It would check if you specifically specified e.g. `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` CMake variable or if `CXX` environment variable
3. It tries to call compilers in the following order (with assumption that one of those is in the `PATH` environment):

   ```
   CC [TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX]c++ [TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX]g++ aCC cl bcc xlC clang++
   ```

**References**

- [CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:30 (project): No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801638/cmake-error-at-cmakelists-txt30-project-no-cmake-c-compiler-could-be-found)
- [Environment variable used by CMake to detect Visual C++ compiler tools for Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069632/environment-variable-used-by-cmake-to-detect-visual-c-compiler-tools-for-ninja)

Comment: I deleted VS2017, it now gives me an error simular to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869564/cmake-on-windows . The difference though, my console can find gcc, but cmake doesn't see it? Could this be due to me setting PATH in console before calling the rest, and cmake only sees system-wide changes?

Comment: Yes, and I keep deleting CMakeCache.txt and CMakeFiles, but no difference.

Comment: (i'm not sure if you are receiving notifications, so just in case)

Comment: @GregoryBalko If you are on Windows, the default is the Visual Studio/NMake generator. Without knowing which GCC you are targeting, I just assume adding `-G "Unix Makefiles"` would solve your problem.